# google + and facebook style iframe youtube video. by default shows video image, when image clicked video plays

Tags: java, javascript, youtube, embed, thumbnails

I already have a plugin that embeds videos on my site called oembed. What I need is a javascript code that converts  youtube iframes or another embeds to the default image of the videos, when the image is clicked video player appears and plays. Google + and facebook have implemented this idea. Please let me know how to make this happen.

This is an example of my youtube iframe:

```
<iframe width="267" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBEID;feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I found two codes and modified them into this:

```
var RE = /embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/;

jQuery( "iframe" ).each(function(){

var id = ( this.src.match( RE ) || [] )[1];

if( id ) {
jQuery( this ).replaceWith( 
                            '<img   width="420" height="215"  src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'+id+'/hqdefault.jpg"'+
                            ' class="youtube" />' );
}
});
var youtubeIFRAME = '<p class="close">CLOSE</span><iframe data-address="$1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

jQuery("img.youtube").click(function(){
var $this = $(this);   
$this.replaceWith('<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'                  
                  .replace("$1", $this.attr("data-address")));
});
```

The problem is now the embed works but there is a problem catching the video Id.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's a link element surrounding your iframe. I believe you can fix that by removing the link and using something else, like a div:

```
function changeiframe() {
objs = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (i in objs) {
        if (objs[i].src) {
        vidid = objs[i].src.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
        linkurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+vidid;
        bgurl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/0.jpg';
        imgurl = 'playsh.png';
        container = document.createElement('div');
        container.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+bgurl+')';
        container.className += "youvid";
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = imgurl;
        container.appendChild(img);
        objs[i].outerHTML = container.outerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! The code only works in google chrome.