# Click overlay div to play youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, embed

I have a placeholder div overlaying a youtube iframe. I'm trying to click on the placeholder and play the video using jquery. It seems very simple, but I can't for the life of me figure this out. Could anyone help me with this?

Here's the html I'm working with:

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="placeholder"></span>
   <iframe id="video width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/abqjFFtAPRo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you're trying to do.  If you're trying to get an 'icon' over the video then I don't really see a point in that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902718/google-and-facebook-style-iframe-youtube-video-by-default-shows-video-image?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

To made this fast i suggest to you this functionality. You need a button/link with the video source url. On the url you need to pass the parameter "autoplay=1". When you click the element, puts the video source on the attribute "src" of your iframe ;) Le code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loadVideo").bind("click", function(){
          videoUrl = $(this).attr("data-video-src")
          $("#video").attr("src", videoUrl)
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <button id="loadVideo" data-video-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/abqjFFtAPRo?rel=0&autoplay=1">Load video</button>
      <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen/>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use the http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video_id]/0.jpg to set a static image of the video :)

Comment: Yeah, this is great! that makes perfect since :) Thanks Ronan

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a double-quote after your `id` attribute.

I've also created a CodePen (http://codepen.io/j_shb/pen/hJKaE) that shows how to position a span over an iFrame and then bind a click event with jQuery. (Not sure why the video embed isn't working in my example — I think it might be CodePen's fault.)

Does any of that help?