# Html css play/start youtube videos after clicking an image

Tags: html, css, youtube

I am learning html and css and also css3.

I need create play youtube videos. For that i have raised one doubt,

Is there any possibilities to run youtube videos after click an image by only using html and css or css3?

Can anyone please guide me?

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE"
   width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: So your question is, 'Is there a way to achieve.. when you click an image, that image turns into a youtube video that begin plays?

Comment: Normally you have to use JavaScript like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129455/click-overlay-div-to-play-youtube-video?rq=1

Comment: yes @CharlesAnthonyBrowne: my goal is to achieve only using html and css. so i am asking this question regarding playing videos.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with just HTML/CSS. You need to use JavaScript and call the [YT-iFrame-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Example-Code:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.youtubeImage', function() {
  callYoutubeApi();
});
```

Comment: are you sure?.. @roNn23

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. Well, you don't have to use the API, because you can also use some other techniques (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129455/click-overlay-div-to-play-youtube-video?rq=1), but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle

Comment: Please try it on your own. If you ran into problems, create a new question, as this question is only about HTML/CSS.